# EF 6: adding new table in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

After adding table `Person` to database and updating the model from database table, entity `Person` exists, but is not present in

```
Entity ctx = new Entity();
ctx.Persons // doesn't exists
```

How can I fix that? Thanks

Update: table had 2 foreign keys, after I delete one of them - `Persons` appeared in `ctx`. Is there any constraint to have 2 foreign keys?

Update №2: EF named table `Person` as `People`. WTF???

Comment: EF named this table `People` because that's the proper English plural form for `Person`

Answer (score 1):

[Ef pluralization of tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for table names is performed unless you specify a [table name via annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#TableColumn) or using fluent API   `modelBuilder.Entity<TPoco>().ToTable("TName", "schema");`

Would need to see exception and Custom DBContext class to comment further.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but you don't provide a lot of context for your question, check some online tutorial like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tutorial-series-updated-for-entity-framework-6-code-first-with-mvc-5.aspx